# ImageMagick: target-size is ignored?

Tags: imagemagick

Original image is 3.7M, this command produces file size of 2.7M, but I want 2M:

`convert in.jpg -define webp:target-size=200000 out.webp`

Also tried `target-size=2MB`.

Related documentation: https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php

```
 $ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-13 Q16 x86_64 2021-10-29 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib jng jpeg ltdl png tiff webp x zlib
Compiler: gcc (11.2)
```

Gentoo.